# Where to store Ansible host file on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to get started with Ansible to provision my Vagrantbox, but I can’t figure out how to deal with host files.

According to the documentation the should be storred in `/etc/ansible/hosts`, but I can’t find this on my system (Mac OS X). I also seen examples where the `host.ini` file situated in the document root adjacent to the vagrant file.

So my question is where would you store your hostfile for setting up a single vagrant box?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

While Ansible will try `/etc/ansible/hosts` by default, there are several ways to tell ansible where to look for an alternate inventory file :

- use the `-i` command line switch and pass your inventory file path
- add `inventory = path_to_hostfile` in the `[defaults]` section of your `~/.ansible.cfg` [configuration file](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html)
- use `export ANSIBLE_HOSTS=path_to_hostfile` as suggested by DomaNitro in his answer

Now you don't mention if you want to use the [ansible provisionner available in vagrant](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html), or if you want to provision your vagrant host manually.

Let's go for the Vagrant ansible provisionner first :

Create a directory (e.g. test), and create a Vagrant file inside :

**Vagrantfile**:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise64-v1.2"
  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"

  config.vm.define :webapp do |webapp|
    webapp.vm.hostname = "webapp.local"
    webapp.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.123.2"
    webapp.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 200, "--name", "vagrant-docs", "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    end
  end

  # 
  # Provisionning
  #
  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provision.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "hosts"
    ansible.sudo = true
    #
    # Use anible.tags if you want to restrict what `vagrant provision`
    # Here is a list of possible tags
    # ansible.tags = "foo bar"
    #
    # Use ansible.verbose to see detailled output for ansible runs
    # ansible.verbose = 'vvv'
    #
    # Customize your stuff here
    ansible.extra_vars = { 
      some_var: 42,
      foo: "bar",
    }
  end
end
```

Now when you run `vagrant up` (or `vagrant provision`), Vangrant's ansible provionner will look for a file name `hosts` in the same directory as Vagrantfile, and will try to apply the `provision.yml` playbook.

You can also run it manually, without resorting to Vagrant's ansible provisionner :

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts provision.yml --ask-pass --sudo
```

Note that Vagrant+Virtualbox+Ansible trio does not always get along well. There are some versions combinations that are problematic. Try to upgrade to the latests versions if you experience issues (especially regarding network).

{shameless_plug} You can find an more extensive example mixing vagrant and ansible [here](https://github.com/leucos/ansible-tuto/tree/master) {/shameless_plug}

Good luck !

Comment: For later readers: `hostfile` is **deprecated**, use `inventory` **instead**.

Answer (score 47):

If you used Brew to install Ansible, you'll most likely find the default hosts file at `/usr/local/etc/ansible/hosts`. But, as others pointed out, you may just want to change the default.

Comment: Thanks. I had to create directory `/usr/local/etc/ansible/` and put a hosts file in it, unlike Linux.

Comment: @counterbeing same behaviour if you installed via macports. You can do a simlink though

Comment: where is it if you installed it via pip? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-on-mac-osx

Comment: I ended up specifying the hosts file with the `-i` flag as I'm just learning

Answer (score 7):

I like to use bash environment variables as my base project is shared with other users.
you can simply `export ANSIBLE_HOSTS=/pathTo/inventory/` this can be a host file or a directory with multi files.

You can also use write it in your ~/.bash_profile so its persistent 
A bunch of other variables can set that way instead of maintaining a conf file for more info check the source in ansible/lib/ansible/constants.py

Answer (score 6):

Here is a description what to do after installing Ansible on Mac, it worked for me: [ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible/install/)

I downloaded the ansible.cfg file to

```
/Users/"yourUser"/.ansible
```

and afterwards you can edit the ansible.cfg file by uncommenting the

```
inventory      = /Users/"yourUser"/.ansible
```

line and specifying the path to the ansible folder like shown above. You can create the hosts file in this folder then as well. To try it out locally, you can put

```
localhost              ansible_connection=local
```

in the hosts file and try it out with

```
ansible -m ping all
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Vagrant's ansible provisioner, Vagrant will automatically generate an Ansible hosts file (called `vagrant_ansible_inventory_default`) and configure ansible-playbook to use that file. It looks like this:

```
# Generated by Vagrant

default ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

It calls the Vagrant host "default", so your plays should either refer to "default" or "all".

Answer (score 0):

On Mac i used `sudo find / -type d -name "ansible" 2> /dev/null` to find it,
but i don't have `.../ansible/hosts` folder from the box, maybe because i installed using `brew` as i read above, so i created at path`/etc/ansible/hosts`