# Cannot find neither ~/.ansible.cfg or etc/ansible

Tags: ansible

I installed ansible using pip

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo pip install ansible
```

But I cannot find either `~/.ansible.cfg` or `etc/ansible` in macOS.

```
$ansible --version

WARNING: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way. This will fail in a future version of macOS. Set the LIBRESSL_REDIRECT_STUB_ABORT=1 in the environment to force this into an error.
ansible 2.10.0.dev0
  config file = None
  configured module search path = [u'/Users/nethminiromina/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/nethminiromina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.16 (default, Oct 17 2019, 17:14:30) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s
```

How can I find or setup inventory file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ansible-config`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-config.html) to show the config file location

```
% ansible-config --version
ansible-config [core 2.13.1]
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/Users/myusername/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/myusername/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/ansible-config
  python version = 3.9.7 (v3.9.7:1016ef3790, Aug 30 2021, 16:39:15) [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

In this case I had no configuration file (`config file = None`) so I generated an empty one (option `--disabled` means all entries are commented out) in the current directory with

```
% ansible-config init --disabled > ansible.cfg
```

Now `ansible-config` can find a configuration file in the current directory `/localDir`

```
% ansible-config --version                    
ansible-config [core 2.13.1]
config file = /localDir/ansible.cfg
[ . . . ]
```

**Note**: consider security issues [Avoiding security risks with ansible.cfg in the current directory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#avoiding-security-risks-with-ansible-cfg-in-the-current-directory).

Here's the priority list of places where Ansible will search for a config file (see [configuration file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#the-configuration-file)):

- `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (environment variable if set)
- `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
- `~/.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
- `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Answer (score 2):

> Q: *"Cannot find etc/ansible"*

A: `pip show -f ansible` should show the installed files. If the configuration file is missing create one. See [Configuring Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour).

> Q: *"How can I find or setup inventory file?"*

A: See [Where to store Ansible host file on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958727/where-to-store-ansible-host-file-on-mac-os-x).